# Initialize std::vector in class's initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, vector, initialization

I'm not sure if I should ask this at StackOverflow or at CodeReview. But because I couldn't find a similair problem, I'm posting it here.

ATM I'm optimizing the code of a simple image manipulation application.

One of the targets is to give all the convolution effect classes their respective matrix as their private variable. Because const-correctness this wasn't done earlier, but the quickfix to solve the introduced problems with const-correctness wasn't sparely with memory and cpu-cycles.

So I decided to init the convolutionMatrix at class-initializiation-level with a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` since creating dozens of constructors to make each initialisation with `std::array<std::array<double>,\d+>,\d+>` possible, is inefficient.

```
BlurFilter::BlurFilter() : ColorEffect(), convolutionMatrix(
std::vector<std::vector<double>>{
    std::vector<double>{ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
    std::vector<double>{ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 },
    std::vector<double>{ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 },
    std::vector<double>{ 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 },
    std::vector<double>{ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 }
} )
{
}
```

However. the application breaks at runtime in the Matrix constructor with an `std::out_of_range`-exception with the what()-message:

> what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)"

Aka multidimensionalVector.size() is somehow 0.

```
Matrix::Matrix( const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& multidimensionalVector )
{
    this->xLength = multidimensionalVector.size();
    this->yLength = ( *multidimensionalVector.begin() ).size();
    this->values = multidimensionalVector;
}
```

Honestly I don't understand why the size of the multidimentsionalVector is zero at that moment at all since I'm passing an initialized vector of vectors which could be -as shown- copy-constructed (or move-constructed) over to the values-variable of the Matrix class. Changing multidimensionalVector copy-by-value don't make the difference.

Could someone explain where and/or what is going wrong here?

(PS: I'd prefer answers written in own words (aka in Plain English) instead of citing directly from the C++ standard documents because of the used vague and confusing academic/scientific language).

Comment: If it's a true matrix it would be more efficient to create a 1d vector and use the index calculation (x + y * width) to find the element. You can wrap this in a class for convenience.

Comment: We need a little more code to help you here. Can you show us where you create the `BlurFilter` and how the matrix is passed to `Matrix`'s constructor?

Comment: Actually the standard doesn't use "vague" language. Cryptic, maybe. Confusing, certainly to some. Abstract, hell yes. but vague no. It's the verbose english that is vague and open to interpretation.

Comment: Works fine at http://ideone.com/7VXnQk.

Comment: Have you tried a very basic repo?  I just did one and it worked OK.  It was just a class accepting a vector of vectors in the constructor, assigning it to a private member, and main creating an instance, passing in an initialised (as you have) vector of vectors.

Comment: Which compiler and version and flags you are using could be useful for a diagnosis.  Oh, and have you considered a `std::unique_ptr< std::array< std::array< ` or a `shared_ptr`?  Do you have forwarding ctor support?  Can you produce a simple, self contained example that generates your error?

Comment: @FélixCantournet: The aim of the Standard is to be precise, unambiguous and clear. In that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, This is embarrassing of me.

It seems I've fixed my own problem unintentionally when I was stripping and optimizing my code for posting this question. I didn't thought about to try out the streamlined code before posting it.

Putting

```
this->values = multidimensionalVector;
```

did the job.

The original of the Matrix-constructor which seemed to raise the `std::out_of_range`-exception was this:

```
Matrix::Matrix( const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& multidimensionalVector )
{
    this->xLength = multidimensionalVector.size();
    this->yLength = ( *multidimensionalVector.begin() ).size();

    for( int x = 0; x < this->xLength; x++ )
    {
        for( int y = 0; y < this->yLength; y++ )
        {
            this->set( x, y, multidimensionalVector.at( x ).at( y ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Within `Matrix::set(int x, int y, double newValue )`, the x and y parameters are always checked if they're in between -1 and this->xLength && between -1 and this->yLength.

But the x and y parameters are never checked if they're in bounds with the (then not initialized) this->values...

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, you can simplify your code quite a bit. Here's an example that works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Matrix
{
   Matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& multidimensionalVector);
   size_t xLength;
   size_t yLength;
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> values;
};

Matrix::Matrix( const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& multidimensionalVector ) : xLength(0), yLength(0), values(multidimensionalVector)
{
    this->xLength = values.size();
    std::cout << "xLength: " << xLength << std::endl;
    if ( xLength > 0 )
    {
       this->yLength = ( *values.begin() ).size();;
    }
    std::cout << "yLength: " << yLength << std::endl;
}

struct BlurFilter
{

   BlurFilter();

   Matrix convolutionMatrix;
};

BlurFilter::BlurFilter() : convolutionMatrix( { { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                                                { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 },
                                                { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 },
                                                { 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 },
                                                { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 } } )
{
}

int main()
{
   BlurFilter f;
}
```

Comment: This is cool! I have two questions. Can I access Matrix elements using convolutionMatrix[row][col]? And can I create a `std::unordered_map< std::string , Matrix >` to store or point to a bunch of these things ? Thanks!.

Comment: I don't think it works for a one dimensional array, does it? I get an error.

Comment: How do I create a Matrix of a certain dimensions without providing an initialiser list?

Comment: @SimonWoodward, you can use `BlurFilter::BlurFilter() : convolutionMatrix(M, std::vector<double>(N)) { }` for that.